# Boot Issue After Formatting and Changing Mounting Points

Tags: boot

Sorry in advance for my poor screenshots since I can't boot up!

For some reason my 2nd internal NVMe drive was inaccessible, so I messed around with it in a partition app by formatting it which didn't work, then I changed the mounting point which allowed me to access it as an admin. Still awkward, but it worked. I did the same deal with my Kindle.. had to change mounting point and needed sudo to access it.

However, I seem to have broken my boot configurations in this process. I am using an encrypted drive, and after unlocking the drive it goes into Emergency Mode. The console output during this process is below.

[image: Console Output]

After researching similar Ubuntu issues, I am still unable to get it working but I do know from reading that stuff that my /etc/fstab and blkid may help deduce what is wrong:

[image: /etc/fstab and blkid]

I did also eventually make two changes to my etc/fstab. If you see the comments added when the partition app changed it to use the UUIDs instead of the filepaths. I thought maybe this was the issue, and changed them back to the filepaths as they were when I installed Elementary, but the boot process is still broken.

One other thing that may help... it is booting to the grub bootloader now, but it used to boot straight into Elementary...

Any help or direction to get me booted up without losing files on my HD would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To boot into single user mode you edit the boot instructions for the GRUB menu entry you wish to boot and add the kernel parameter/option single. Brief instructions for how to do this are below.

Turn on laptop and wait when GRUB menu will appear. Select (highlight) the GRUB boot menu entry you wish to use. Use the first one entry in this case.

Press e to edit the GRUB boot commands for the selected boot menu entry.

Look near the bottom of the list of commands for lines similar to

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.7.0 root=UUID=bc6f8146-1523-46a6-8b
6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro quiet splash initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.7.0
```

Change the line by removing quiet splash and by adding the kernel boot parameter single to the end of the line (it should look exactly like this: ro single).

For this example you would change:

```
6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro quiet splash
```

to

```
6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro single
```

Press either Ctrl+X or F10 to boot using these kernel options.

Note: These changes are not persistent. Any change to the kernel boot options made this way will only affect the next boot and only if you start that boot by pressing either Ctrl+X or F10 while still in GRUB edit mode.

Then run the system and see errors on the screen and provide a photo of the screen with errors or information the system shows.

Then you should hit Enter to go into maintenance mode and type in terminal.

```
journalctl -xb
```

and hit Enter.

It will show you all information from the boot start process to the end, I mean to the moment you hit Enter to go into maintenance mode. To quit viewing hit q.

Provide screenshots. Use arrows or PgUp PgDown to scroll text in the screen.

Then very important step is to show the fstab.

```
sudo cat /etc/fstab
```

Example: how fstab should look like:

```
UUID=89ef95ac-3c86-4b94-a37c-da8c72a148fa /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=8b4947b6-c0c9-4b1f-87ed-ef698609be22 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=C8CA-DC0F  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=21f30bb7-2c7a-405f-bb16-b37901eeda09 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=c98dd990-02e1-4872-9de0-d00601e5aa7a none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Edit the /etc/default/grub

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and change:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

to this:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="mount.timeout=300s"

ctrl+o saves, ctrl+x exits

Type

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg and restart.
```

To restart type:

```
 systemctl reboot
```

And hit Enter.

Then you can repeat all steps but instead of hitting Enter, hit Ctrl+d to run the system.

See will it load with default options.

The same effect you will achieve when you will hit Enter instead Ctrl+d and then type:

```
systemctl default
```

and hit Enter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mount trick with fstab.

You can try to use command:

```
mount -a
```

Then command:

```
mount
```

to see  what is mounted.

And if you will display what is in mtab with this command:

```
cat /etc/mtab
```

You will see mounted disks.
You can copy those which should be mounted during the boot process and paste them into /etc/fstab.